# Splitting argument using regular expression with limit

Tags: perl

```
$aa = "Main:http://google-test.com:8080/service"

(or)

$aa = "http://google-test.com:8080/service2"
```

I want to split this into two parts:

```
Main:

http://google-test.com:8080/service
```

But it is not working with this split:

```
split (/\:/,$aa,1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need change the limit from 1 to 2.

```
perl -le 'my $aa="Main:http://google-test.com:8080/service"; my @parts = split(/:/, $aa, 2); print scalar @parts;'
```

From [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If LIMIT is specified and positive, it represents the maximum number
>   of fields the EXPR will be split into,

It looks like you were trying to use it as the maximum number of times to split and not the number of parts to return.

Answer (score 1):

New question, new answer:

```
my ($a1, $a2) = $aa =~ /^(\w*):?(http://.+)$/;
```

Assuming the "Main" part can only be alphanumerics. This will also match `$a1` to the empty string if "Main" is left out, which you can check for with an if statement or similar.

Split would work too, with a limit of two, as gpojd has already answered.

```
my ($a1, $a2) = split /:/, $aa, 2;
```

But then you would need to check and see what you caught in the two variables. E.g. the URL could be in either `$a1` or `$a2`. And you might need to join them back together afterwards.

Comment: Do you by your edit mean to say that "Main" is sometimes not there?

Answer (score 0):

You want to split it at the colons?

try:

```
my @DATA;
$aa = "Main:http://google-test.com:8080/service";
@DATA = split(/:/, $aa);
```

Then you can access the different parts of the split using:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < @DATA; $i++)
{
  print "data section $i value is: " . $DATA[$i] . "\n";
}
```